# javascript regex questions

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a used a javascript replace to wrap all words seperated by a space, but it does only wrap numbers and letters, but i want it to wrap every character like dots, comma's, quotes etc

i have used this regex pattern

```
string.replace(/\b([\w+-]+)\b/g,'<b>$1</b>')
```

Comment: If you want to wrap everything, how do you decide what _not_ to wrap?

Comment: Everything must be wrapped, so its all single wrapped tags seperated by a space or one massive wrapped tag

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Perhaps you might edit the question to include desired input/output examples.

Comment: if you look at the code above you will see that every word/number will be wrapped in a bold tag, if you hit space it will create a new bold tag(its a lot like the the tags that you can enter if you write a question here)

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get what you're after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wrap anything that isn't a space, make your regex match everything that isn't a space. Try this one:

`/([^\s]+)/g`

Comment: Why use `[^\s]` when there is `\S`? Also, I think you mean "word," not "string."

Comment: actually i meant space, not string. And yeah `/(\S+)/g` would work too

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something here, or wouldn't

```
'<b>' + string + '</b>'
```

suffice?